# Recursing Properly Through Related Entities

Tags: php, json, recursion, visualization

I have a set of Organizations and their Board Members. 
All organizations have board members and many board members are on the board of more than one organization.

I am using [JIT Hypertree](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Hypertree/example1.html) to illustrate their relationships. The JIT Hypertree schema requires that one item be the parent of all and is drawn based on a single JSON array.

I would love to have the re-centering event query and re-populate the graph based on the change. Then 2 levels would be fine but I have not been able to work out how to do that.

The code I have at present recurses manually for three levels from the starting organization but what I want is to re-curse through all related records.

So it would start with an Org and add Org's array of children (board members). Then fetch all of the boards (other than current Org) for each board member and add those as children of the board member.

This would continue until each trail dead ends - presumably at a board member who only belongs to one board.

Anyone have advice on how to create this array and avoid duplicates?

```
$board = $center->board();

$top['id'] = $center->ID;
$top['name'] = $center->Org;
$top['children'] = array();
if ($board) {
    foreach ($board as $b) {
        $child['id'] = $b->ID;
        $child['name'] = (strlen(trim($b->Last)) > 0) ? $b->First . ' ' . $b->Last : 'Unknown';
        $child['data']['orgname'] = $center->Org;
        $child['data']['relation'] = $b->Role;
        $child['data']['occupation'] = $b->Occupation;
        $child['children'] = array();
        $childboards = $b->boards();
        if ($childboards) { foreach ($childboards as $cb) { 
            $gchild['id'] = $cb->ID;
            $gchild['name'] = $cb->Org;
            $gchild['data']['orgname'] = (strlen(trim($b->Last)) > 0) ? $b->First . ' ' . $b->Last : 'Unknown';
            $gchild['children'] = array();
            $childboardmembers = $cb->board();
            if ($childboardmembers) { foreach ($childboardmembers as $cbm) {
                $ggchild['id'] = $cbm->ID;
                $ggchild['name'] = (strlen(trim($cbm->Last)) > 0) ? $cbm->First . ' ' . $cbm->Last : 'Unknown';
                $ggchild['data']['orgname'] = $cb->Org;
                $ggchild['data']['relation'] = $cbm->Role;
                $ggchild['data']['occupation'] = $cbm->Occupation;
                $ggchild['children'] = array();
                $gchild['children'][]= $ggchild;
            }}
            $child['children'][]= $gchild;
        }}
        $top['children'][] = $child;
    }
} 
$top['data'] = array();
$top['data']['description'] = $center->Desc;
echo json_encode($top);
```

// Edit 2011.10.24  In Re hakre response
My data structure is a table of Organizations with unique IDs, a table of People with Unique IDs, and then a bridging table for the two specifying Organization (Entity) and Person and the Role the Person is playing in the Entity.  A typical many-to-many.  No sub-boards at all.  I made an image of it which now seems kind of pointless but I'll add it at the bottom.

The JIT library data structure is a little nuts (to me) in that it goes like this in their band example:

```
Top: Nine Inch Nails
  Child: Jerome Dillon
    Child:  Howlin Maggie (another band)
      {all the bands' members and then all of their bands...}
```

So the organization (band) is treated as though it is a Person even though it is comprised of a number of Persons.  And when I recurse using the code above I get (I think) terrible bloat but the JSON it makes works correctly despite bloat.

Example [JSON](http://nolasatellitegovernment.tulane.edu/js/Jit/orgmap.js.php?oID=244) and [Example Visualization](http://nolasatellitegovernment.tulane.edu/network_mapping.php?oID=244)
// End Edit

[image: schema]

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hard to answer in the sense that your data-structure is mainly unknown.

For the graphical represenation you only need to provide simple relationships if I understand that correctly:

```
*- Parent
   +- Child
   +- Child
   ...
   `- Child
```

Your data structure has a different format, I don't know specifically but it's something like:

```
Org <-- 1:n --> Board

Board <-- n:n --> Board # If you have sub-boards

Board <-- n:n --> Member
```

Whichever your data is represented, to map or transpose your data onto the required structure for the graphical representation, you need some functions that take care of that.

To do that you need to share classification/type between both and specific keys, so that you can look-up the needed data from the event to return the data. For example:

```
if (request_parent_is_org())
{
    $id = request_parent_id();
    $parent = data_get_board($id);
    $parent->addChildrent(data_get_board_children($id));
}
else
{
    ... # All the other decisions you need to take based on request type
}

view_response_to_json($parent);
```

Comment: Hi hakre, thank you for the response!  I have clarified my schema and commented on schema of JIT library JSON.  Please take a look and see if it has implications for your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you have with your many-to-many data model is a [*graph*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).  JIT is designed for [*trees*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29).

To put it another way, JIT will not correctly show the crossing lines that are represented in the data whenever a single person is connected to multiple organizations.

I'd recommend a proper network graph visualization - [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html) has a great implementation for modern browsers.

The JSON data format it uses is actually easier to implement given your table structure - for all the organizations and people, you define objects:

```
{
    "name": "Mme.Hucheloup",
    "group": 1
},
{
    "name": "Afton School Board",
    "group": 2
}
```

And for each association in your association table you define connection objects that wire them together:

```
{
    "source": 1,
    "target": 2
},
```

The fancy coding in D3 takes care of the rest.  Good luck!

Comment: Actually JIT's hypertree does exactly what I want it to do and does what you say it won't.  Check out Mayor Mitch Landrieu's node here:  http://nolasatellitegovernment.tulane.edu/network_mapping.php?oID=10    Thanks for the link though!  While not what I am aiming for the force directed graph is fun!

Comment: Just for kicks I made a demo using my whole dataset and the Force Directed Graph.  The Links array is strictly by numeric index so have a unique board member nodes as you' have to make a scheme to know which index you'd stuck Mayor Landrieu into.  So each board plots as a separate graph.  Still kind of fun!  http://nolasatellitegovernment.tulane.edu/vis/d3/force/

Comment: Here's another go with an added indexing array keyed to my objects' ids and storing their numeric index in nodes[].  Has some odd artifacts where board members who are connected to more than one board have a free floating duplicate node.  All in all fun but not what I'm after.  Added zooming in for kicks; scroll down over a node to see the whole map.    http://nolasatellitegovernment.tulane.edu/vis/d3/force/linked.html

Comment: Ahh... Seeing your real dataset, I would revise my decisive-sounding claim that this is a graph.  It's _barely_ a graph and _mostly_ a tree.  I only see a few instances where the many-to-many exists, and you're right JIT handles that OK.  I was thinking you were looking at more of a social network like, say [linkedIn Maps](http://inmaps.linkedinlabs.com/0 (many of peer-peer interconnection).  That kind of thing would

Answer (score 2):

You can use function below:

```
function get_orgs_and_childs ($child_id, $found = array()) 
{
    array_push ($found, $child['name']);

    if($child['children'])){
            $found[] = get_parents($child['id'], $found);
    }
    return $found;
}
```

Call it using:

```
$orgs = get_orgs_and_childs($child['id']);
```